# MessageBox.Show Error, can not convert from string to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window

Tags: c#, messagebox

I am developing a desktop application in Visual Studio 2012 and Sql Server 2012. It has been running well
until now. Now, following error is being displayed in each line of the code where I have used `MessageBox.Show("String");` function.

```
cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'
```

I don't remember whether I deleted any necessary libraries or not.
As I think, all necessary libraries are included in the project like `System.Windows.Form` etc.... 
Please help me to figure out my error... 
a sample line of code with error is

```
 MessageBox.Show("Enter Product Name");
```

Comment: can you show the exact code that's failing? Are you passing any other parameters to `MessageBox.Show()`?

Comment: Not sure how you accomplished this... Do other form objects work ok? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) msg box should be in same assembly as all other form controls. (`System.Window.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll`)

Comment: Something's wrong with your assemblies (either references or the assemblies themselves) and the compiler can't find the right MessageBox.Show() overload. Unfortunately, I don't know how this might have happened. Possibly a conflicting version of the `MessageBox` class got defined in your own code somewhere? Corrupted assemblies in the GAC? You'll have to double-check everything to figure out where this overload is coming from.

Comment: Which version of the MessageBox class do you *want* to use? This seems to be Windows.Forms. Did you mean to use the WPF version?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your comment. I got the solution from your comment. Actually I created user defined class with the name MessageBox which already is the part of Windows.Forms. That is why the conflict was occurring. Sorry I don't have the permission to vote up.....

Comment: @IkramKhan: based on your reply, I've added the correct answer with some advice about possible ways to fix it. That should make it easier to find the correct answer if someone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you have a conflicting class named `MessageBox`, with a `Show()` method.

You should change the name of your own user-defined `MessageBox` class so that it doesn't conflict. If that's not possible for some reason, you can use a `using` directive to define an alias to ensure against the conflict.